# Adding Macros in Scheme

Tags: macros, scheme, lisp

For a college project we're working on learning scheme however we've been thrown into a difficult assignment with little knowledge. We're given certain functions like "'let", "'cond", "and'" etc. and asked to add macros.

```
(define eval
  (λ (e env)
    (cond ((symbol? e) (lookup-var e env))
          ((not (list? e)) e) ; non-list non-symbol is self evaluatory
          ;; special forms go here:
          ((equal? (car e) 'λ)      ; (λ VARS BODY)
           (let ((vars (cadr e)) (body (caddr e)))
             (list '%closure vars body env)))
          ((equal? (car e) 'if)
           (eval_ (if (eval_ (cadr e) env) (caddr e) (cadddr e)) env))
          ((equal? (car e) 'quote) (cadr e))
          ;; Add More Macros Here:
          ;; ((equal? (car e) 'let) xxx)
          ;;((equal? (car e) 'cond) xxx)
          ;;((equal? (car e) 'and) xxx)
          ;((equal? (car e) 'or) xxx)
          (else (let ((eeoe (map (λ (e0) (eval_ e0 env)) e)))
                  (apply_ (car eeoe) (cdr eeoe)))))))
```

So basically we're asked to fill in the blanks, where the ';;' comments are.
I tried doing the 'cond part and got this

```
((equal? (car e) 'cond)
           (env (cdr e) env))
```

But I have no idea if it's correct (very little knowledge of scheme). Any help in figuring this out will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really macros but special forms you are adding. If you know that `let` is just syntax sugar for anonymous function call. eg.

```
(let ((a expr1) (b expr2)) body ...)
```

is supported in you evaluator already if you change and evaluate:

```
((lambda (a b) body ...) expr1 expr2)
```

To get you going `let` works like this:

```
(let ((bindings (cadr e))
      (body (cddr e)))
  (eval_ `((lambda ,(map car bindings) ,@body) ,@(map cadr bindings))))
```

Now real macros you would introduce a new type of `%closure` so that whenever you find it as operator you bind the symbols not their evaluation, run the evaluator on it as if it was a function, then do `_eval` on the result. Then instead of implementing `cond` and `let` you could just add a function on how to rewrite it down to something you already support. Thus you could make `let` like this:

```
((lambda (let)
   (let ((a expr1) (b expr2))
     (cons a b)))
  (~ (bindings . body) `((lambda ,(map car bindings) ,@body) ,@(map cadr bindings))))
```

It assumes you have quasiquote and `map`, but it could easily be implemented without these with more verbose code. `~` is just chosen randomly to be the macro version of `λ`. When evaluated it makes perhaps a `%mclosure` structure and you need to handle it specially to not evaluate its arguments, but evalaute the result. From that on you could support the special forms by having predefined `%mclosure` in the boot environment.